# .NET VisualStudio wsdl multiple xsd files, overlapping definitions

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, wsdl

I'm writing an implementation for a mailing service and I'm having trouble with the code that VisualStudio autogenerates from the wsdl file. The API contains several versions of the same objects. The objects are defined in separate xsd files corresponding to a particular version:

[image]

Although each xsd file defines a specific namespace, the complex element names are the exact same in all xsd files:

[image]

This causes VisualStudio to assign arbitrary names to the classes representing the complex names to retain uniqueness:

[image]
[image]

If you look at the xsd files, OpenMailingGroup_13B returns an OpenMailingGroupResponse and OpenMailingGroup_15A also returns an OpenMailingGroupResponse, and IMHO that's ok from a definition point of view because they are defined in separate xsd files each having its own separate namespace. However, when VisualStudio generates the proxy classes, it names the return type of OpenMailingGroup_13B as OpenMailingGroupResponse2 and the return type of OpenMailingGroup_15A as OpenMailingGroupResponse4.

This becomes an issue when you update the web service reference and new versions are added and removed (e.g. a new OpenMailingGroup_17X now exists). The problem is that VisualStudio would now use a different naming for the OpenMailingGroupResponse. What was OpenMailingGroupResponse4 for OpenMailingGroup_15A could not be OpenMailingGroupResponse9. And that breaks our code.

We thought of a few possible solutions:

1. Writing adapter classes - but there are literally hundreds of classes and that would be too painful.
2. Using var in the variable definition in order not to hardcode the type, but there's lots of nesting involved (e.g. a complex type has another complex type which has another complex type, etc.).
3. Not update the wsdl...

So, my question is: can I tell VisualStudio to split the generated code into multiple .NET namespaces, each corresponding to its xsd file? Maybe a general question is: is there anything I can do about this?

Thanks in advance,

Tiberiu